# Django foreign key in registration model

Tags: django, django-models, user-registration

I am using Django 1.7.

I need to develop a user registration model in which at the time of registration, user will have to enter an employer also along with username, email and password. The employer name should be there in the database. Besides the custom user model, I am using another model named employer.

What would be the best way to implement this through a custom registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cleanest way, using  `OneToOneField(User)`

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    //here goes your others employee attributes
```

So when you create your user model,also create its employee instance.